# How to add rows lost by a join back into the data frame?

Tags: python, pandas

I am currently trying to automate an Excel process that was poorly set up into a Python program with pandas. Mostly everything was working correctly, but I noticed a few rows were dropped that I need in the final output. They were dropped because I used a right join and there was nothing for the rows I need to join on in that sheet. I tried experimenting with different joins, but they would completely mess up the final product, and this is single digit rows missing with a few tens of thousands of rows correct. Is there a way to get these rows into the final product, or is there a better way to go about doing this?

Looking at one of the categories with a missing row, here are my data frames that I am joining. I tried getting them to print in a way that I could copy into a code block, but I could not figure out a way to make them look nice, so sorry about having to use the links. I also replaced each number with ## as I am not sure I can include them. I put exclamation points in the row of interest. There are no entries for 2021 in the first data frame but I still need the row for 2021 in the second data frame to be added into the merge data frame.

[First df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7h6z.png)

[Second df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ziiUU.png)

[Merged df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJkJt.png)

[Desired Merge df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CsceI.png)

My merge looks like this:

```
merged_df = rdPy.merge(pt, how = 'right', on = ['Category', 'AY'])
```

I tried doing something like this:

```
merged_df.loc[(merged_df['Total'] != 0) & (merged_df['RsvT'].isnull().any()), 'LossP'] = merged_df['Loss']
merged_df.loc[(merged_df['Total'] != 0) & (merged_df['RsvT'].isnull().any()), 'ALAEP'] = merged_df['ALAE']
merged_df.loc[(merged_df['Total'] != 0) & (merged_df['RsvT'].isnull().any()), 'ULAEP'] = merged_df['ULAE']
merged_df.loc[(merged_df['Total'] != 0) & (merged_df['RsvT'].isnull().any()), 'AAO-ULP'] = merged_df['AAO-UL']
```

It did work, but it required a different type of join which screwed up all the other rows. Sorry for the post being confusing as there are a hundred or so lines of code, so I just tried to include the important stuff. Any help is appreciated and if I need to clear anything up, I will do my best to answer.

Comment: Please add your 'merge' line of code

Comment: I added the line to the post.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you right, try using 'outer':

```
merged_df = rdPy.merge(pt, how = 'outer', on = ['Category', 'AY'])
```

Comment: I did switch to using outer, but I originally thought that was what was screwing up my final output, but it was actually the 4 lines of code that I wrote which was trying to copy the values from the original loss, ulae, alae, and aao-ul columns to the P columns. I think it has something to do with my .isnull usage, but I have not figured what is wrong out yet.

Comment: I think removing the any part fixed the issue, thanks for the help.